# Extended Language Support for Infragistics

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

Currently, my application has the following infragistics language files loaded.

```
infragistics-bg.js
infragistics-de.js
infragistics-es.js
infragistics-fr.js
infragistics-ja.js
infragistics-ru.js
```

Based on the infragistics documentation, other languages are supported already. May I ask where can I download the complete set of files to fully introduce a new language to my application like the following.

```
infragistics.ui.popover-bg.js
infragistics.ui.scroll-bg.js
infragistics.ui.splitter-bg.js
infragistics.ui.toolbar-bg.js
.....etc.
```

I am aware that in infragistics, a custom language file can be created from scratch but I was wondering if these types of files are readily available for all of their supported languages. I was hoping to introduce support for Portuguese(pt-PT).

I tried checking the contents of the other language files I have thinking that I might be able to replicate it with other language by translating them one at a time, but it seems like it would be tedious and counter-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This respository stores resource strings for the [Ignite UI for Angular internacionalization.](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular-i18n)

The English resource strings and the interfaces for each localizable component's `resourceStrings` property are stored in the [Ignite UI for Angular repository](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular). The interfaces can be used as a schema for creating custom resource strings.

You can check the PRs for more detailed examples on how the previous i18n's were added.

Enjoy.

Comment: I am new to Infragistics and it seems like I failed to include more specific information. I am looking for IgniteUI language files but not for Angular. Through the repositories that you mentioned, I was able to find them - https://github.com/IgniteUI/ignite-ui/tree/master/src/js/modules/i18n.

Unfortunately, it was still not complete as there were other files that I also need and were not included in the OSS package.

This was still a good help though. Thank you!